# m2eclipse Missing Artifact

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse, maven-3

I am trying to get started with Maven and m2eclipse but I keep getting missing artifact errors:

[image]

`log4j` is in my local repository. I have m2eclipse set up to use an external installation of Maven although I realize that for dependency resolution it uses the embedded maven. I don't have any custom settings for maven set up, this is a plain install of m2eclipse and maven. I am able to add the dependencies I want through m2eclipse (such as log4j) and it adds them to my pom file. I am at home and not behind a corporate or particularly restrictive firewall.

Can anybody help me figure out what is going on?

Pom file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.xonatype.mavenbook.ch04</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-weather</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>Simple Weather</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <type>bundle</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>20040902.021138</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change `<type>bundle</type>` to `<type>jar</type>`

Comment: I can't believe that worked. I caught that as well but the GUI was throwing a fit about changing it to jar. After changing to jar in the pom.xml file it works.

Comment: What is the difference between bundle and jar - how would one know to select one or the other?